# Running celery beat worker in my Django application

Tags: django, django-celery

I am using celery for my Django project and to run celery beat worker I use the command

`celery -A <projectname> worker -B`

This works fine but if I want to execute this command from my application

I run this command

`celery -A path\to\projectname worker -B`

Then I get this error ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.

This is my directory structure.

```
project
|-- 1
|-- build.csv
|-- build_info.csv
|-- celerybeat-schedule
|-- db.sqlite3
|-- application
|   |-- !
|   |-- !!
|   |-- 1
|   |-- admin.py
|   |-- admin.pyc
|   |-- celery_task1.log
|   |-- celery_tasks.logs
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- __init__.pyc
|   |-- models.py
|   |-- models.pyc
|   |-- tasks.py
|   |-- tasks.pyc
|   |-- templates
|   |   |-- admin
|   |   |   `-- application
|   |   |       `-- download_csv_report
|   |   |           `-- change_form.html
|   |   `-- application
|   |       |-- index.html
|   |       |-- jenkinschart.html
|   |       `-- jenkins.html
|   |-- tests.py
|   |-- urls.py
|   |-- urls.pyc
|   |-- views.py
|   `-- views.pyc
|-- project
|   |-- celery.py
|   |-- celery.pyc
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- __init__.pyc
|   |-- settings.py
|   |-- settings.pyc
|   |-- urls.py
|   |-- urls.pyc
|   |-- wsgi.py
|   `-- wsgi.pyc
|-- manage.py
|-- start.py
|-- static
```

This is my error stack trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shopclues/project/env/bin/celery", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/shopclues/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 14, in main
    _main()
  File "/home/shopclues/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 326, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/home/shopclues/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 488, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "/home/shopclues/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 279, in execute_from_commandline
    argv = self.setup_app_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/home/shopclues/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 481, in setup_app_from_commandline
    self.app = self.find_app(app)
  File "/home/shopclues/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 503, in find_app
    return find_app(app, symbol_by_name=self.symbol_by_name)
  File "/home/shopclues/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/utils.py", line 355, in find_app
    sym = symbol_by_name(app, imp=imp)
  File "/home/shopclues/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 506, in symbol_by_name
    return imports.symbol_by_name(name, imp=imp)
  File "/home/shopclues/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/utils/imports.py", line 56, in symbol_by_name
    module = imp(module_name, package=package, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shopclues/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/imports.py", line 101, in import_from_cwd
    return imp(module, package=package)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
```

Is there any way I could run celery beat worker command from my application.Any help would be appreciated

Comment: by saying "execute this command from my application" you mean you want to run celery dynamically via python code?

Comment: No,Running the command from application directory

Comment: can you post the stack trace please and the directory structure

Comment: Error stack trace??

Comment: ImportError: Import by filename is not supported. It is in the question.

Comment: That's not stack trace. I mean post your terminal content. you must be seeing  some sequence of lines before you see `ImportError: Import by filename is not supported`

Comment: and I believe you're running both commands from your project root directory?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193245/discussion-between-xxbinxx-and-miller).

Answer (score -1):

If you are in root directory of your Django application and have added your celery app to django settings. You `celery.py` file should looks something as below.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings
from my_django_app import settings as app_settings

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_django_app.settings')
APP = Celery('my_django_app', broker=app_settings.BROKER_URL)

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows. 
APP.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
APP.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

Then you can run your commands as something like this from Django root directory

```
celery -A my_django_app worker -B
```